# Searching database using `LIKE` and `MATCH AGAINST` in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a table in my database called pro_search where I have translated the meta information for different products in different languages.

My table structure is like so:`id   pro_id  en  de  es  fr  it  nl  pl  pt`
where `pro_id` is the id of the product and the two letter code in the other columns represent the language of the translation of that products meta data.

I ran the following code to create a FULLTEXT indexes on my database:

```
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FullText` (`en` ASC, `de` ASC, `es` ASC, `fr` ASC, `it` ASC, `nl` ASC, `pl` ASC, `pt` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `enFullText` (`en` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `deFullText` (`de` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `esFullText` (`es` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `frFullText` (`fr` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `itFullText` (`it` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `nlFullText` (`nl` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `plFullText` (`pl` ASC);
ALTER TABLE pro_search ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `ptFullText` (`pt` ASC);
```

[image]

I then tried to do a few tests to see what results I would get back:

```
$lang = 'en';
$term = 'this is a test';

$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE $lang=?;";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '1' so there is definitely a match

$params = ['%'.$term.'%'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE $lang LIKE '?';";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '0'

$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE MATCH ($lang) AGAINST ('?');";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '0'

$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE MATCH ($lang) AGAINST ('?' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '0'

$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE MATCH ($lang) AGAINST ('?' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '0'

$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE MATCH ($lang) AGAINST ('?' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION);";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
// returns '0'
```

As you can see the first exact query returns a result, and if I do a query directly in phpMyAdmin of `SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE en LIKE '%test%'` I get 7 total results but none in my second query here in my php file which is exactly the same.

Am I missing something here? I thought all of these should be returning at least one result if not more.

### Edit

Here is my create code for my table as it stands just in case it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `pro_search` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pro_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `de` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `es` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `it` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `FullText` (`en`,`de`,`es`,`fr`,`it`,`nl`,`pl`,`pt`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `enFullText` (`en`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `deFullText` (`de`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `esFullText` (`es`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `frFullText` (`fr`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `itFullText` (`it`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `nlFullText` (`nl`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `plFullText` (`pl`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `ptFullText` (`pt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1597 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Also, how would people recommend searching in multiple languages? I set it up this way that the product meta is translated, but we don't have a translator so some of them are straight from Google translate with just a few changes here and there. However, if I get this working I might try creating an index directly from the products table that includes product title, description and meta.

The way I see it I have two options:

1. Store product translations and search these, or
2. Translate the search term and search in English

Either way we're probably going to be dealing with bad Google translations.

Comment: The screenshot is phpmyadmin so I would guess MySQL

Comment: @jarlh Yeah MySQL and phpMyAdmin

Comment: From a design point of view, would it be better to just have a text column and another which is the language code.  This would save having so many indexes and would also mean you can easily add a new language at any time.

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah i'll probably change this around. I had it set up differently previously (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147321/php-sql-improving-search-feature-fuzzy-search) and am testing out different options now but just struggling to get it to return anything at all at the moment

Comment: How many rows in your test?  What is the typical number of words in each meta column?

Comment: @RickJames Over 1500 columns, between 30-100 characters each

Comment: You have mixed a debugging and a strategy question in one post. Good luck getting a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `'` around your ?

```
  $params = ['%'.$term.'%'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE $lang LIKE ?;";
  $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  echo $count.'<br />';
```

In the first statement you are adding the string parameter without any quotes: `$lang=?`. This would imply that you do not need the single quotes around the `?` for other statements;

Answer (score 1):

Only the first query have no quotes.

So DB::run is adding quotes.

Remove quotes from all MATCH ... AGAINST queries.

This way they should work all.

EDIT:
try this

```
$params = [$term];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pro_search WHERE MATCH ($lang) AGAINST (?);";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count.'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `DB::run($sql,$params);` adds quotes to the string?  If so, it creates

```
WHERE en LIKE '"stuff"'
```

Remove your quotes.

Comment: This is not the issue. Adding the actual quotes around the variable results in an SQL error. Where as this actually gives me a result, even if the result is '0' and not what I was expecting

Comment: @PaddyHallihan - I'm confused -- The only result the code asks for is $count, which will be 0 because of the spurious quotes.  If you are also getting an error, what is the full text of that error?